# If $A$ is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix, then $\det(A)=a_{11}\det\left(M_{11}\right)-a_{12}^2\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

From Section 2.1 in Steven J. Leon & Lisette de Pillis's [Linear Algebra with Applications](https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/linear-algebra-with-applications/P200000006241) (10th edition):

> **Problem 13.** Let $A$ be a symmetric tridiagonal matrix (i.e. $A$ is symmetric and $a_{ij} = 0$ whenever $\lvert i-j \rvert > 1$). Let $B$ be the matrix formed from $A$ by deleting the first two rows and columns. Show that
> $$ \det (A) = a_{11}\det \left( M_{11} \right) - a_{12}^2 \det (B).$$

---

My Attempt:

> Here $M_{11}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by deleting the first row and the first column of $A$.

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric tridiagonal matrix. We use induction on $n$. Here we can assume without any loss of generality that $n = 3, 4, 5, \ldots$.

> For $n = 3$, we have
> $$
> A = \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 0 & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix} \right],
> $$
> where
> $$
> a_{12} = a_{21} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad a_{23} = a_{32}. \tag{1}
> $$
> Then
> $$
> B = \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{33} \end{matrix} \right]. 
> $$
> So
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \det (A) &= a_{11} \det \left( \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix} \right] \right) - a_{12} \det \left( \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{21} & a_{23} \\ 0 & a_{33} \end{matrix} \right] \right) \\ 
> &= a_{11} \det \left( M_{11} \right) - a_{12}^2 a_{33} \\
> &= a_{11}\det \left( M_{11} \right) - a_{12}^2 \det (B). 
> \end{align}
> $$

> Now suppose that the given result holds for all symmetric tridiagonal matrices of order $k \times k$, where $k = 3, \ldots, n-1$. Let $A$ be a symmetric tridiagonal matrix of order $n \times n$. Then
> $$
> A = \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45} & 0 & \ldots & 0 &  0 \\ & & & \vdots & \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{n, n-1} & a_{nn} \end{matrix} \right], 
> $$
> where
> $$
> a_{12} = a_{21}, a_{23} = a_{32}, a_{34} = a_{43}, \ldots, a_{n-1, n} = a_{n, n-1}.
> $$

How to proceed from here?

Or, is there some other more suitable approach?

Comment: Why are you quoting yourself? 

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I didn't get you. Where is it in this particular post that I'm quoting myself?

Comment: 95% of your post is a quote, i.e., you use `>` all over

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you for your comment, but that's how I have for years been inserting my proofs (or attempted proofs) on this platform.

Comment: Why?  How can one distinguish a quote from your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of a matrix can be computed by using the [Lagrange expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along any one of its rows or columns.

By using the Lagrange expansion along the first row of the matrix $A$, you get that

$\det(A)=a_{11}\det(M_{11})-a_{12}\det(M_{12})\,.$

Moreover, by applying the Lagrange expansion to the first column of the matrix $M_{12}\,,\,$ you get that

$\det(M_{12})=a_{21}\det(B)\,.$

Since the matrix $A$ is symmetric, it follows that

$\det(M_{12})=a_{12}\det(B)\,.$

Consequently ,

$\det(A)=a_{11}\det(M_{11})-a_{12}^2\det(B)\,.$

Comment: What a beautiful answer!!